# Using HTML classnames as metadata

Tags: html, css, metadata

Should I be using class names in HTML page that describe it completely, eg. `navbar-static-8` to describe a fixed navbar containing 8 items? 
Or should I be wrapping the metadata into separate attributes e.g. `type="static" items="8"`.

I want such names to be parsed in javascript.

Comment: Use `data-` attributes for storing custom values.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner would be to use data attributes like:

```
<div data-type="static" data-items="8"></div>
```

John Resig wrote a nice article about this http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

But if "static" refers to something you want to use for the design of the item, you should use classes since these are designed to be used in CSS. The data attributes are more used in Javascript as meta data about the object.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `navbar-static-8` type of name of class , and you can 'type="static" items="8"' your custom attribute but test on all browser (specially `Intenet Explorer`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use descriptive class names for a intuitive css use, like **"navbar navbar-static"** and use the html5 data for js, like **data-navitems="5"**
Make use of cascading, use two css classes, **navbar** to describe general nabvars properties, and **navbar-static** to describe styles only for the static navbars.